# SSL peer handshake fails when installing MonetDB via Homebrew

Tags: ssl, homebrew, monetdb

I'm installing MonetDB as per the instructions at [1], but Homebrew says the SSL peer handshake fails:

```
$ brew install monetdb
==> Downloading https://dev.monetdb.org/downloads/sources/Jan2014-SP3/MonetDB-11.17.21.zip

curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
Error: Failed to download resource "monetdb"
Download failed: https://dev.monetdb.org/downloads/sources/Jan2014-SP3/MonetDB-11.17.21.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem arose because I had not updated Homebrew after an upgrade to MacOS Yosemite. After running `brew update` everything works. Should have thought of that before posting my question, sorry!

Comment: I did a clean install of macOS 10.10, fresh install of brew, but am unable to run `brew update` due to the server mirrors.edge.kernel.org requires a client certificate to connect; plus an encouragement to upgrade from: git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61). My next move is to freshen up my version of git somehow... @HRVHackers tip not work for me at this stage due to `invalid option: --with-libssh2`.

Answer (score 0):

brew update didn't work for me, but this did

```
brew reinstall curl --with-libssh2 --with-openssl
```